# SQL insert query takes too much time in migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I am migrating data from one un-normalized database to another normalized. I could migrate almost all the data but got to the point where a query lasts around 5 mins and I think its too much.

Here is the Entity-Relation Diagram:

Diagram of normalized database

[image]

And a picture of the un-normalized database:

Un-normalized database

[image]
The table that I want to complete where I have the problem is "Items" and the query is:

```
INSERT INTO LOS_CAPOS.Items (Item_Factura_Nro, Item_Compra_Cod, Item_Factura_Monto, Item_Factura_Cantidad, Item_Factura_Descripcion)
SELECT f.Factura_Nro, c.Compra_Cod, Item_Factura_Monto, Item_Factura_Cantidad, Item_Factura_Descripcion
FROM LOS_CAPOS.Facturas f
INNER JOIN gd_esquema.Maestra m ON f.Factura_Nro = m.Factura_Nro
INNER JOIN LOS_CAPOS.Compras c ON c.Compra_Fecha = m.Compra_Fecha AND c.Compra_Cantidad = m.Compra_Cantidad
```

Facturas is a 7664 rows and Compras is a 78327 rows table

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Is it simply that the `SELECT` is too slow?

Comment: Gordon Linoff has the point - you need to add if running the SELECT without INSERT is slow or not. Also, gd_esquema.Maestra is not on the diagram. I'd guess that LOS_CAPOS.Compras is not looked up optimally, as its PK is not in the join but rather 2 other columns and those might not even have an index, as well migth be the case with  gd_esquema.Maestra.

Comment: Yes, the select query is slow. Maestra is the unnormalized table, I mean almost all the columns of all normalized tables of the diagram are in that table, where a lot of data are null or repeated. What index do you recommend?

Comment: See the query plan - the DB engine issues a missing index recommendation and that is usually the most efficient solution. Any query tuning/optimisation can only be done by seeing the query plan. And you need to know that an index will slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations as the index needs to be updated as well. So there are different indexing scenarios for which table, which column, read vs write considerations, no ultimate solution exists that solves slowness.

Comment: So which index do you recommend on which columns to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start testing the SELECT only by commenting out a join (and the related columns coming from that table) and see which lookup is causing slowness. After that check if you can use other columns that are indexed to do the lookup. Ideally you would join LOS_CAPOS.Compras on its PK. If you can't, start testing as I mention below, by picking a column, create a non-clustered index, and test all SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations on that table to see the impact.

Any query tuning/optimisation can only be done by seeing the query plan. And you need to know that an index will slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations as the index needs to be updated as well. So there are different indexing scenarios for which table, which column, read vs write considerations, no ultimate solution exists that solves slowness.